# Vertical display of Header Text in Grid View ASP .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to display the headerText of the Grid View vertically?

http://img371.imageshack.us/img371/4813/testyk6.jpg

I hope the above link works

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe you'd have to use images.  Either created at design time, or using a HttpHandler to generate images at run-time if they need to be dynamic.  Make all of your fields use TemplateFields and place the image in the HeaderTemplate.  Kind of tedious, but it's the only way I can think.  Perhaps some third party grid controls can handle this.

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight can do this (as can Flash, I'm sure). CSS3 will support it. But graphic text is the way to go right now.

You can use any of several text-hiding techniques in CSS to show the text for accessible browsers, yet display the graphic (with text arranged vertically) for sighted users.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it IE using the following CSS although it might be limited to browser, version etc...

writing-mode: tb-rl;
filter: flipv fliph

Comment: I've used this in Intranet systems and it always seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

[Stu Nicholls](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/vertical.html) has an interesting HTML/CSS technique, if a bit HTML verbose.  However, it doesn't do the word rotation that you're looking for.  Just throwing out another option.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind an IE only solution, you could use some of the css filters that IE supports.  Something like this:

```
<div style="width:100%; filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);">
    This text is rotated 90 degrees.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In IE7+ you can use the DX transform:

```
writing-mode: tb-rl;
filter: flipv fliph;
```

In older IE (for the poor souls still stuck with it):

```
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

In Safari/Chrome (anything webkit based) you can use the transform:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
```

The latest FX builds have an equivalent:

```
-moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
```

But that's not mainstream yet.

I've been trying to do this with graphic text, but have a [few problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388677).

Answer (score 0):

I used a 
break (br) command between each letter

Answer (score 0):

```
/*Do this in a loop for each header cell so Cells[0] to cells[however many] and however long the string is so use length properties to get the actual length of the text string */ 

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         StringBuilder vtxt = new StringBuilder();
            vtxt.Append(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString().Substring(0,1));
            vtxt.Append("<br />");
            vtxt.Append(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString().Substring(1, 1));
            vtxt.Append("<br />");
            vtxt.Append(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString().Substring(2, 1));
            vtxt.Append("<br />");
            vtxt.Append(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString().Substring(3, 1));
            vtxt.Append("<br />");
            vtxt.Append(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString().Substring(4, 1));
            vtxt.Append("<br />");
            vtxt.Append(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString().Substring(5, 1));
            vtxt.Append("<br />");
            vtxt.Append(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString().Substring(6, 1));
            vtxt.Append("<br />");
            vtxt.Append(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString().Substring(7, 1));

            GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[2].Text = vtxt.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide a short description for the above code to improve the accuracy of the post :)