# Rotating an image using css

Tags: css, image, rotation

I'd like to rotate an image on a webpage through four orientations at 90 degrees apart.  I'd prefer this to happen on the client machines.  Can this be done using css?  Or will I need to use javascript?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: since it is 2013 now, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11832483/926460), it just works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in Firefox using [these CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms) - as for other browsers, I think you'll need Javascript. I'd recommend you perhaps take a look at the [Raphael library](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Comment: This looks like an excellent library and will save me a lot of work.  Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible however only for new browsers.

[Best Link I could find (Chrome / Safari / Firefox) with example](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-transform)

[Sample source code (Safari/Chrome)](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/)

[Sample source code (Firefox)](http://www.ditii.com/2008/09/16/css-transforms-in-firefox-gecko/)

[SO post containing code for IE Webkit and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716970/rotating-table-header-text-with-css-transforms)

Comment: Thank you for the links.  Some interesting effects here!  At the moment though, it looks like I will have use javascript until browsers catch up.

Answer (score 1):

Afraid you're gonna have to use some javascript for that - CSS cannot do this currently

Try checking this out:

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/