# Keep Rotated Image "In Bounds"

Tags: css, rotation

I'm trying to rotate an image by a random angle using the solution suggested here: [How to add a rotated image in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939161/how-to-add-a-rotated-image-in-css)

The problem is that the image ends up going out side the bounds of the location it was originally supposed to be at times.  This shows what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/jBHRH/82/  See how the corners of the image are cut off?

Is there a way with CSS or HTML to keep this from happening?  Maybe something to do with `background-size: contain;`?

**EDIT**: I'm displaying this in a table cell with borders.  So, when it's rotated, it ends up going beyond the bounds of the borders.

Comment: Maybe the obvious answer...if the image were square it wouldn't be a problem :)

Comment: Are you calculating the rotation programmatically? You could use that to assign `left: XXpx; position: relative;` where XX is equal to the rotation offset.

Comment: @remus: Yes, I'm generating the rotation angle with PHP.  How would you calculate the "rotation offset"?

Comment: heh, nevermind. width auto wins

Comment: Change your second div to </div>. Any particular reason you need to use a table?

Comment: @TimSPQR: I need a table because this is part of a larger installation in which the framework is built as a table.  I could display the images within a table within that table though.  Or in a <div>, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I just set the width to:

```
width:auto;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LB3dG/

Comment: Sorry, but I forgot to mention that I'm displaying these images in a table cell with borders.  I tried the applying this to my application and it wasn't working for some reason.

Comment: @gtilflm Hmm, I saw your mentioning on that in your post and tried it. Well `border:2px black solid` on the `#cell` "worked" but had a space between the lower end of the image and the border...don't know.

Comment: No dice. Check out what changing the height to "auto" does: http://jsfiddle.net/LB3dG/2/

Comment: @gtilflm Ok, you have to change that always, there is no auto for all. Here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/L4jvS/. The `auto` gets set by the `font-size`, the background image does not change the measurements of the `table`...