# How to rotate Images in HTML using CSS in FireFox..?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Webkit is working in chrome but not in firefox what is the another method for webkit-transform

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform

Comment: .me {
        -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
        -moz-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
        height:2%;
        width:3%;
    }  @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
        from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
        to   {-webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);}
    }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8939302/607874

Comment: I saw your comments below that says that you want animation effect. But your answer does not say that. Ask clearly what you want, you should edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
.rotate{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Chrome, Opera 15+, Safari 3.1+ 
      -ms-transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* IE 9 
          transform: rotate(7.5deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 
}
```

Updated Demo 1: **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/0v1xecnr/)** - This will spin whole div

Updated Demo 1: **[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranm/0v1xecnr/1/)**  - this will spin only image

Comment: If i wanna rotate my image linearly what can i do

Comment: do you need animation over there?

Comment: Yes..rotate my img like progressing using css

Comment: updated my answer.. as per your requirement