# Cross browser way to rotate image using CSS?

Tags: css, image, background, rotation

I have a site layout I'm working on that has a main content area and then
at each of the four corners of the content area sits a corner graphic. The
overall effect is that of a desk blotter.

Here is the code for my top left hand corner:

```
.corner-top-left    { width:96px ;
height:96px ;
background:url("images/corner.png") no-repeat ;
position:absolute ;
top:-5px ;
left:-5px ;
z-index:3000 ;
}
```

Rather than make four individual corner images, what I would like to do
(if possible) is use the original image (corner.png) and rotate it using
CSS.

Is there a cross browser compatible way to do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: A google search would have given you your answer: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1004-how-to-rotate-an-image-with-css/

Comment: I did search google first. That link didn't show up anywhere in the first 10 *pages* of results I looked through (search term was 'css rotate background image'). Since many of the examples I *did* see weren't cross browser compatible, I came here. Thx for the link though.

Comment: You'd better use 4 different images as CSS transforms won't work in IE 7 and IE 8.

Comment: Thanks for the caveat, Ihor. In IE8, the rotation worked great but
it played hell with the shadow transparency of my image. Gah. separate
images it is then :)

Comment: Why not making a single image containing the four corners and using an offset to display only the required one? I see this technique used all the time.

Comment: @xbonez: the link is dead now. :(

Answer (score 55, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/tJkgP/2/

CSS to rotate by 45 degrees:

```
.desk
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 5em auto;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    overflow: visible;
}
.desk img
{
    behavior:url(-ms-transform.htc);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* IE9 */
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    /* IE6,IE7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476);
    /* IE8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; 

}
```

IE6-8 CSS came from here: [CSS rotate property in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617220/css-rotate-property-in-ie)

Comment: This will work great with images that have no transparent elements in them! Thank you :) I make that distinction only because I checked the jfiddle in IE8 and it was playing hell w/ the shadow and transparency. That's IE for you though. Thanks again!

Comment: This is exactly why CSS sucks. Lack of standards is the standard.

Comment: @janek37 it is lacking and explicitly in this case there is NO standard. It would be nice to have a standard `rotate(45deg);` as a banner for all the browser specific ones.

Comment: Would be good to know where does the behavior htc file comes from... and what role plays in the indicated script.