# What's wrong with the image?

Tags: image, cross-browser, jpeg

I got a image: http://images.tyler.lu/iphone-4s-a.jpg
http://images.tyler.lu/iphone-4s-a.jpg

It looks different in different browsers.

- Chrome

  [image]
- IE

  [image]

What's wrong with the image?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe some JPEG attribute that not every renderer parses?

Comment: It's the same image, could you please tell me more details?

Comment: There is a TIFF attribute "Orientation" in the file, set to "3 (rotated 180 degrees)".

Comment: Same problem in a .NET image processor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222053/problem-reading-jpeg-metadata-orientation

Comment: Browser support for EXIF orientation is complicated: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56845 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026441/is-there-a-way-to-tell-browsers-to-honor-the-jpeg-exif-orientation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is Thilo's answer:

> There is a EXIF attribute "Orientation" in the file, set to "3 (rotated 180 degrees)".
>
> Same problem in a .NET image processor: [Problem reading JPEG Metadata (Orientation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222053/problem-reading-jpeg-metadata-orientation)
>
> Browser support for EXIF orientation is complicated:https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56845

And I also found a post about the EXIF "Orientation": [Exif Orientation Tag](http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html)

Thanks Thilo!