# Javascript image preview always in landscape mode bug

Tags: javascript, image

I'm trying to dinamically preview an image in javascript before uploading it, so I got this code from here: [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)">
<img id="output"/>
<script>
  var loadFile = function(event) {
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  };
</script>
```

It works fine, but when I load a picture that's in portrait format, it rotates it automatically and sets it to landscape. How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

It's not rotating the picture automatically. 
When I tested it, it's showing me the correct image and orientation.

You probably are experiencing a problem with the EXIF orientation of your image which is not being honored by the browser.

I suggest you open the image in an image editing software, like Photoshop, make sure it's in portrait, and save it under a new name.

Try your script again and it should work.

If not, try with another image (a portrait image found on the Web).

Comment: any ideas on how to make the image orientation be honored by the browser?

Comment: I don't think you can force it. It's up to the user to submit a file correctly.
Sometimes, when I upload images taken from my iPad on kijiji, my images are not in the right format. Same problem as you. I need to resave them and upload them again.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question but without an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026441/is-there-a-way-to-tell-browsers-to-honor-the-jpeg-exif-orientation

Answer (score 0):

for firefox, you can use [image-orientation](http://caniuse.com/#search=image-orientation)

```
img {
    image-orientation: from-image;
}
```

you could also use [this library](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image):

> JavaScript Load Image is a library to load images provided as File or Blob objects or via URL. It returns an optionally scaled and/or cropped HTML img or canvas element.

Comment: any cross browser solutions? image-orientation seems to only work in FF http://caniuse.com/#search=image-orientation

Comment: From w3: (This property is likely going to be deprecated and its functionality moved to HTML)