# Images being displayed in wrong orientation

Tags: html, css, image

The company I work for stores some of their product images in Google cloud storage, and I've been able to fetch the images however when putting the img tags onto a page, they appear to be in the wrong orientation i.e landscape instead of portrait (no issues with images taken in landscape mode).

When viewing the image in a new tab however they appear correctly!

Is there a reason why this may be? Suggestions are appreciated.

I have tried putting the img on a blank page without an anchor wrapping it to see if that made a difference and it did not.

Comment: please add your code , whatever you've tried so far

Comment: @zeerozeroone Welcome to SO! If the answer given is a correct answer to the question, make sure you mark the answer accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the OP is having problems due to EXIF data.  If the original images contain EXIF data indicating that they should be rotated, special measures must be taken to get that data interpreted by a web browser when displaying a page.  It is discussed here:

[Is there a way to tell browsers to honor the jpeg exif orientation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026441/is-there-a-way-to-tell-browsers-to-honor-the-jpeg-exif-orientation)

If the the solutions provided for exif orientation are not acceptable, the OP will have to preprocess the images to rotate them to proper orientation and save them that way on the serverside.  Then the correctly rotated images can be delivered on web page.

Comment: This is correct. I was able to use PHP's exif functions to rotate the images before uploading.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help!