# Image auto-rotation when loading via File API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas

With Chrome 81 and other new releases, EXIF orientation is observed by default and `image-orientation: from-image` is obsolete (see [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61196140) and [test site](https://image-orientation-test.now.sh/)).

Now when loading a JPEG from a file, can this be used, too? I do get wrong rotation but when loading the same image via url into an image-tag, it comes out correct.

```
var r = new FileReader();

r.onload = function(e) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
        var width = img.naturalWidth,
            height = img.naturalHeight;
        // does not observe EXIF image orientation
    };

    img.src = src;
};

r.readAsDataURL(file);
```