# How to rotate image using javascript/jquery.then i want to create a new pattern.interested in actually manipulating the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image]i have a variable which contains an image.can i rotate the image from javascript.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src='http://www.ittefaq.com.bd/admin/news_images/2013/07/29/thumbnails/image_60156.jpg';
//now i want to rotate this image. is this possible ?
```

i have tried to do it with canvas but it is not giving me desired result.

is this possible with javascript / jquery?

i dont want to use css. it does not serve my purpose.

***interested in actually manipulating the image***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832131/cross-browser-way-to-rotate-image-using-css

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You might want to post some code you've tried.

Comment: What did you try with canvas? if not javascript :|

Comment: try css3 rotate and skew.. do not go for javascript and canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
img.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";
```

jsFiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h229f/1/)

Comment: One may also need to set these others : -moz-transform / -webkit-transform / -ms-transform / -o-transform    not sure their names in the object. (these are CSS names)

Comment: @d'alar'cop: Recently almost all modern browsers support the standard CSS

Comment: Yes, but often we are forced to make things compatible with even IE6 (personal experience). Not a criticism just a note to others having a look in the future.

Comment: @d'alar'cop: You're right!

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting this correct, you want to rotate the image on frontend and are not interested in actually manipulating the image.

You can rotate images using CSS3 Transforms as explained here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

**HTML**

```
<img class="exampleImage" src="http://www.corbisimages.com/images/Corbis-42-18522637.jpg?size=67&uid=c7ebc105-b4a4-4fad-8e7d-99ff79ac2ce4" height="300px"/>
<input type="range" min="-180" max="180" step="1" value="0" id="rotationAngle">
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery('#rotationAngle').on('mouseup', function(){
  jQuery('.exampleImage').css(
 '-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + jQuery('#rotationAngle').val() + 'deg)',
 'transform', 'rotate(' + jQuery('#rotationAngle').val() + 'deg)');
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PPLpG/) is the fiddle for your reference.

Comment: no i want to manipulate the image then i can create a new pattern . i know how to create pattern.

Comment: Looks like all you need is to translate origin and canvas to a different position on grid. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Transformations will help you in doing so.

Comment: thanks. atlast i found some direction.