# How to have four divs reference the same image

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have a div as follows:

```
<div class="panel" style="width: 100%; height: 40px; ">
  <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Panel1" HorizontalAlign="Center" >
    <asp:Image  id="Image2" runat="server"src="../../_images/arrow.jpg"  HorizontalAlign="middle"     style="width: 30%; height: 40px;  " />
  </asp:Panel>
</div>
<div class="panel" style="width: 100%; height: 160px;">
```

I want to have four such divs but reference to the same image. I wonder if I can achieve that in CSS?
Otherwise I have to make 4 copies of arrows.

Comment: You can rotate image using CSS. Please read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832131/cross-browser-way-to-rotate-image-using-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.rot90
{
    transform:rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg); /* Opera, Chrome, and Safari */
}
```