# Change Text and button when you use Toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

Goal:
I want to hide the alphabet "a b c d" and when it is hidden, the arrow shall display with arrow down.
https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_down_alt1-16.png.

It should be a default settings.

When you press the "Hide Text" you toggle out and change the arrow botton into upp and display the text and also you change the text from "Hide Text" into "Show Text"

### https://jsfiddle.net/mxt2pthw/15/

```js
var flip = 0;
$('#test ').click(function() {
  $( "#aaa" ).toggle( flip++ % 2 === 0 );
});
```

```html
<div id="aaa">
a <br/>
b <br/>
c <br/>
d <br/>   
    
 
</div>

<div id="test">
    Test <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_up_alt1-16.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/mxt2pthw/20/

I find the simplest way is to include both images and hide one, then just toggle both on click

```
<div id="test">
    Test 
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_up_alt1-16.png" />
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_down_alt1-16.png" style="display: none" />
</div>
```

In your demo your calculation is inverted to how the data is displayed on load.
Added trigger click as per extra question.

```
$('#test ').click(function() {
    $( "#aaa" ).toggle( flip++ % 2 !== 0 ); // <-- i switched this for the example
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
}).trigger('click'); // trigger on page load
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! As a default when you load this page, the text shall be hidden, not displayed. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Sure, just append `.trigger('click');` so that it runs on load, correcting what's shown. I'll update

Comment: One more thing, I also would like to change the text from "Show Info" to "HIde Info" when you press on the link? Do you have the updated the jsfiddle?

Comment: So **learn from what I've shown you** and apply it to text as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a css class to rotate the image using `rotate` and in js using [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```js
$('#test').click(function() {
  $("#aaa").toggle();
  $(this).find("img").toggleClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {
  /* Firefox */
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* Opera */
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
  /* IE9 */
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aaa">a
  <br/>b
  <br/>c
  <br/>d
  <br/>
</div>
<div id="test">Test
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_up_alt1-16.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Yes check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832131/cross-browser-way-to-rotate-image-using-css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832131/cross-browser-way-to-rotate-image-using-css)

Comment: Thank you for your help! As a default when you load this page, the text shall be hidden, not displayed. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: That example you linked includes a lot more CSS to do that with all browsers

Comment: @HelloWorld Yes, checout this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npu2ncyc/). Adding `hide` class to `img` element.

Comment: Another thing. How about enable to change it from "Hide text" to "Show text"?

Comment: Thank your for your help! Alex. Is it possible to have two picture instead of one because I gonna have 2 different picture?

Comment: Then you can use @Popnoodles solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach :

```
var flip = 0;
$('#test').click(function() {
  $( "#aaa" ).toggle('slow',function(){
      if(flip++ % 2 === 0){
            $("#arrow").attr("src","https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_down_alt1-16.png");
      }else{
            $("#arrow").attr("src","https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_up_alt1-16.png");
      }
  });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this demo:

```js
$(function(){
  var info = [{txt:'Hide Text', src:'up', fn: 'show'}, {txt:'Show Text', src:'down', fn: 'hide'}];
  var test = $('#test'), aaa = $('#aaa'), span = test.find('span');
  var img = test.find('img'), i = 0, o;
  $('#test').on('click', function(e) {
    i = (i + 1) % info.length;
    o = info[i];
    img.prop('src',"https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconic-1/32/arrow_" + o.src + "_alt1-16.png");
    aaa[o.fn]();
    span.text(o.txt);
  }).trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="aaa">
  a
  <br/>b
  <br/>c
  <br/>d
  <br/>
</div>

<div id="test">
  <span></span> 
  <img alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

Comment: When initiate the project you can see that the thing is in motion.