# How to use CSS Rotate() in TH Table Tags

Tags: css, html-table, rotation

I need some CSS guru assistance.

I am trying to create a simple html `<table>` where the column headers (`<th>` tags) have their text rotated 270 degrees to display sideways.

I am having trouble anchoring the header cells so the left-most part of the cell text aligns alone the bottom or baseline of all the `<th>` tags.

I have made many, many attempts a  this and just cannot solve it via CSS.

Can anyone give me some ideas on how to achieve this?

See my jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/franco13/t5GgE/

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: [Vertically rotate text inside an HTML table header cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076052/vertically-rotate-text-inside-an-html-table-header-cell).

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But it does not work. Were you able to peek at my jsfiddle @Vucko?

Comment: @H.Ferrence Check my updated answer to support IE.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it yesterday and it did not work so I moved on...I told my client not to use IE8 (for their private app that I am building). Thanks for the rest of the solution @JoseRuiSantos because that nailed it for me!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/t5GgE/1/

Specify a transformation origin on point (65, 60) for the headers, with no wrap allowed  and make your `td` centered aligned.

```
th.rotate {
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 65px 60px;
    -moz-transform-origin: 65px 60px;
    -o-transform-origin: 65px 60px;
    -ms-transform-origin: 65px 60px;
    transform-origin: 65px 60px;
}

td.rights {
    text-align: center;
}
```

---

**Update for IE8 and below**

For IE8 and below you are forced to use [Transformation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix) instead of `rotate(270deg)`.
So, the correspondent rotation matrix for 270deg is `[0, 1, -1, 0]`.

What you need to do, is add the following and should work just fine for IE8 and below:

```
th.rotate span {
    /* rotated text in IE renders very bad (unless you use clear type), so that even by making it normal, looks less bold but still bold */
    font-weight: normal\9; /* \9 is an hack for IE8 and below */
    letter-spacing: 3px\9; /* because is so bold, need to give letters some space to breath */

    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=0, M12=1, M21=-1, M22=0, SizingMethod = "auto expand");
    width: 150px\9;
    height: 150px\9;
    margin-right: -130px\9;
}
```

**[Final jsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/t5GgE/3/)**

**IE9 problem and workaround**
In IE9, you will see a big black rectangle in the header section, and the reason to this bug is that IE9 recognizes both `-ms-transform` and `filter`. When both CSS are present, the browser simply renders a black area. To workaround this, I sugest you use conditional includes for IE9 to use `-ms-transform` only.

Answer (score 0):

```
  table {
    margin-bottom: 20px; border: solid 1px red
  }
  tr#groups {
    /*display:block;
    margin-left:120px;
    margin-top:120px;*/
  }

  th.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    /*display:inline-block;*/
    height:30em;
    /*float:left;*/
    /*width:30px;*/
  }
  span.intact {
      display: block;
      white-space:nowrap;
    text-align:right
  }
  td.menuItems {
    width: 240px;
  }
  td.no-indent {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  td.indent {
    padding-left:12px;
  }
  td.rights {
    width:20px;
  }
  td,th { border: solid 1px red}
```

i know this is nor final, but I put height in th.rotate and changed span to display: block, nowrap and right align ...
I am sure you will finish this ;o)