# JQuery mobile turn button 90°by default and add to grid

Tags: jquery, button, mobile

How could I realize a button which is turned 90° to the right or to the left by default? I dont want to let him turn onClick, but he should be already turned when the page is loading?

Additionally how could I position this button in a vertical center rightsided to a grid?

Like this:
[image: http://www.abload.de/img/unbenanntfk3b.png]

Thanks,
zY

Comment: You can embed images in your question, makes things a little nicer, btw.

Comment: Done it. Hope it will be useful to all users here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/hnwm9/)

[image]

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="block block_a">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block block_a"></div>
    <div class="button"> button </div>   
</div>
```

---

```
var btn = $('.button');
btn.css('transform','rotate(90deg)');
```

a fix for IE would be replacing the div with an image or just set a separate css playing around with the button styles.

---

As the OP asked *'...Argh! please... make it work in IE!?...'* ;) here is an example on how to do that:

### [DEMO FOR IE 8,7,(and believe it or not) 6!](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/qTZRh/1/)

Just add to the previous code - and modify for your needs the 'px' to best position the DIV

```
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version<="8.0"){
    btn.css({
        filter: 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1)',
        top:'100px',
        left: '184px'   
    });   
}
```

**ONE ONLY THING... (sad but true)**

The IE DX filter only permits 4 stages of rotation (1,2,3,4) , so you won't be able to rotate an element by a fancy degreed position like 37° or doing like : `BasicImage(rotation=2.3)`.

Comment: perfect, is there a fix for IE? in IE the button is not rotated... thanks

Comment: yeah. your example is based on fixed pixel-sizes, is it possible to adapt this dynamically? this means, always to the right of the content area and centered?

Comment: Yes! i am at work now. as soon as i'll have free - i'll make a demo! with the ie fix too

Comment: zyrex... my apologies for the delayed response. I added a demo! look and let me know! (P.S. I've '+1' your question cause it's clear and useful to all other users!)

Comment: thanks thats very useful, one last question as mentioned above, is it possible to provide an example without fixed heights and weights? thank you

Comment: This should do the trick. You still need to fine-tune a bit the jQuery css for the button. Play around: http://jsfiddle.net/qTZRh/12/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get what you're after a 100% but my first guess would be to just use the CSS `writing-mode` property ('`lr-tb`' in your case).

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-text-20010517/#PrimaryTextAdvanceDirection

Comment: its going the right direction, how do I apply this to my button? <a href="#" id="clickme" data-role="button" data-icon="minus" >Collapse</a>

Comment: Oh, apparently this CSS3-property isn't as supported as it should be.... See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716970/rotating-table-header-text-with-css-transforms

Comment: thanks this works! any idea how to set its position next to the right side of block a?