# How to eliminate the white space when I rotate a table cell?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to show in a table some cells rotated, but in this example the columns has a white space. I would like to remove it, but I haven't accomplished how to remove it.

Here is the example:

http://demos.davidjs.com/ST-RotateTableCellContent/

Comment: By whitespace, do you mean the empty space as in item8 after rotation?

Comment: [**JSFiddle Hosted**](http://jsfiddle.net/PAfRY/)

Comment: @TheDeadLike that's right

Comment: @DarfZon: Is there any reason you did not apply the `vertical` class to all of the relevant cells?  For example: http://jsfiddle.net/PAfRY/1/

Comment: Well, in my real application. I just need to apply the `vertical style` to all header cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function adds a div with `height: width, width: height`, however, since your table td inherits the widest cell's width, which in this case `Dummy text`, applies to the rotated cell `item8` to have height of the auto-cell-width of `Dummy text` in horizontal.

You could just leave off the div as your table cell will already try to fit into it's content, or use `display:table-cell` on your `div` to do the same thing.

Comment: thank you, I've got it. Just one more question, how can I center the `vertical-align` to center in the rotated cell?

Comment: Since the layout is rotated, but not reformed(meaning the former width will look as the height after rotation), perhaps `text-align:center` should do the trick.

Also found this possible duplicate to what you're trying to accomplish: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/716970/rotating-table-header-text-with-css-transforms