# What's a good way to dynamically generate PNGs in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have a need to generate small PNG images in ASP.NET.  The images could have things like simple geometries and text.  Is it necessary to use a 3rd party library to generate images in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(300, 300);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

g.Clear(Color.Transparent);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 100, 100, 100, 100);

g.Flush();
bmp.Save("test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394297/generate-transparent-png-c))

You'd have to play around with the contents of the image of course, but the graphics namespace probably has most of what you need.

Comment: For some reason, I never noticed the Clear method. I've always manually used FillRectangle for the entire surface, so thanks kprobst. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can do that just using the [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) and other graphics related classes in the .NET framework.

```
        Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmpImage);
        //Draw using gr here

        //stream to the client
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";

        //write to memory stream first, png can only be written to seekable stream
        using(MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
          bmpImage.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Png);
          memStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        }
        bmpImage.Dispose();
```

Comment: You *must* wrap a using clause around all System.Drawing objects (Graphics, Bitmap). MemoryStream doesn't even do anything a dispose time, ironically.