# Difference when using Graphics.DrawString

Tags: c#, asp.net, gdi+

I get different result using Graphics.DrawString when rendering a chart for ASP.NET website. Text looks fine on development environment but bold and ugly on production. 
Chart sample on production [is here](http://www.amiproject.com/templates/MSFApplicationDevelopment).
I can not post the link on chart sample from development environment, but I uploaded it on AmiProject website with name GanttChartOnDevelopment.png
I have checked that required font in installed on production server.
Code I am using:

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
m_Font = new Font(fontFamily, 8, FontStyle.Regular);
m_Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapWidth, RowHeight * taskCount, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
m_Bitmap.MakeTransparent(m_Bitmap.GetPixel(1, 1));
m_Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(m_Bitmap);
m_Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
m_Graphics.DrawString(Text, m_Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(r.Right + 7, r.Top - 7));
```

I am  using .net 3.5. Production server is Windows 2008, Development - Windows XP SP3.
Please help to understand the reason of that difference and fix that.

Comment: ClearType is enabled on the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Can you make an alpha transparent PNG with C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388677/can-you-make-an-alpha-transparent-png-with-c)

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure if this will make a difference drawing to a bitmap but have you checked that ClearType is enabled on the server?