# How to convert an Image in C#

Tags: c#, png, jpeg

So basically im struggling on converting an image. Like the image in the picture box is JPG but I want to save it as PNG, does anyone know the basic syntax in doing this?

Comment: A Google search for "C# image converter" seems to have some useful results.

Comment: Show us code. Otherwise it will be closed. Meanwhile try something like: `image.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Png);`

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     // Load the image.
     System.Drawing.Image image1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"C:\test.bmp");

     // Save the image in JPEG format.
     image1.Save(@"C:\test.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

     // Save the image in GIF format.
     image1.Save(@"C:\test.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);

    // Save the image in PNG format.
    image1.Save(@"C:\test.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);        
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twss4wb0(v=vs.90).aspx
and also [C# - Convert Jpg to Png with index transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996425/c-sharp-convert-jpg-to-png-with-index-transparency).
Hope this helps!